# Affect only vertices with more than 2 edges in Geometry Nodes

Tags: vertices, edges, vertex-groups, geometry-nodes

I want to build a road in Geometry Nodes. For that I want the the input to be a mesh line. The Line follows the Path of the road.

I want the node tree to "see" junctions, AKA vertices with more than two edges. Is there a way to get these values in Geometry Nodes?

Thanks alot in advance, first time posting here, hopefully I didnt forget anything :D

Edit: Using 3.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a very simple solution

[image: Here's a very simple solution]

and here is the result

[image: Example of geometry nodes]

This relies on the [Vertex Neighbors](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/vertex_neighbors.html) node, which, as the name implies, provides a count of how many vertices are connected to a give vertex by edges (or faces.)

Obviously in my example you will want to replace the *Mesh Circle* with however you want to draw the intersection, but it's fairly simple in 3.1

You want an intersection wherever there are more than 2 neighbors, so use a simple math *Greater Than* set to 2 to set the selection.  Feed that and the original geometry to an *Instances on Points* nodes, and use whatever you'd like for your instances.

Answer (score 3):

Node setup:

[image]

The node setup creates a cube (you can do there whatever you want, i just wanted to make the result visible) whenever there is a cross section which i defined as vertex count = 4 neighbours.

[image]

Note: i hope/think every 4 year old kid knows that you could use a "greater than" node instead of the "compare + not" nodes to get the "exact" goal of the question.

Comment: Very nice :). Can't imagine doing this in any way without GN

Comment: thank you and...well ...with python ;) or animation nodes....or sverchok ;)

Comment: yeah well, that's just a list of more things I never learned :))